# CSS rotation animation breaks in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, css-animations

I stumbled upon a weird behaviour in Safari today, and I cannot figure out what causes the problem.

When creating an animation that rotates an SVG element in a certain pattern, with everything working perfectly fine in Chrome, Safari only shows half the SVG on every animation step.

When I remove the `background-color: white;` from the `.container` element, everything works fine. How would a background color be causing such a behaviour?

Here's a demo video as well as the corresponding JSFiddle:

**JsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/04zgmbup/

**Chrome (expected):** 
[image: Expected Animation Result in Chrome]

**Safari (unexpected):**
[image: Unexpected Animation Result in Safari]

Comment: you need to include svg tag to get the needed help ;)

Comment: you are using SVG so you need to add the SVG tag to your quesiton for better visibility (already done)

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about HTML tags. Thanks for your edit!

Comment: Maybe this tells you a bid more https://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: *All the 3D transformation functions ...... should be considered “future” SVG* . A quote from [Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5: Vector Graphics for Web Design](https://www.amazon.com/Using-SVG-CSS3-HTML5-Graphics/dp/1491921978/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1544887212&sr=8-5&keywords=amelia+bellamy-royds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so apparently I got this problem figured out.

**Safari seems to be handling the container background as a plane.**
This means that when the item rotates, one half will always get rotated behind the container, which has a white background color which covers the element itself.

I still do not know why other browsers do not behave like this.
A possible solution for Safari could be to `translateZ(width /2)` the element, so that all rotations happen in front of the background plane.

Here's the updated fiddle, working in Safari:
https://jsfiddle.net/04zgmbup/1/

The problem can be visualized nicely by giving the container a semi-transparent background color. In the below recording, one can clearly see that half the circle gets rotated behind the container.

[image: Problem clearly visible with a semi-transparent background]